# click and scroll fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I use fullpage.js and I've a little problem, I've 3 buttons which are used to scroll on différents sections. 
My question is : How can I go on a specific page by using button, and  which boutton can I use to ? (On fullpage.js)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] - In order to answer you question, you need to provide a [mcve] - Otherwise, we'll be guessing as we cannot solve a coding issue without seeing the code that's causing the issue

Answer (score 3):

With Full page **moveTo** Function, you can depend on index of button in button group, like for example:
HTML:
Button Group:

```
<div class="buttons-group">
    <button class="ui button"></button>
    <button class="ui button"></button>
    <button class="ui button"></button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.buttons-group').on('click',function() {
    $("#fullpage").fullpage.moveTo($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

where as for my fullpage sections look like this:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

or any similar methods, like depending on button id, and make the id contain section index number.

Comment: That's the way! ;)